# Информация в alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так,чтобы когда на всех вопросах стояло ***правильно*** ,то высвечивалась информация в `alert` со словами - "вы выиграли".

Вот мой код:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: "#draggable",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Правильно!");
    }
  });



  $("#draggable2").draggable();
  $("#droppable2").droppable({
    accept: "#draggable2",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Правильно!");
    }

  });


  $("#draggable4").draggable();
  $("#droppable4").droppable({
    accept: "#draggable4",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Правильно!");
    }

  });


  $("#draggable5").draggable();
  $("#droppable5").droppable({
    accept: "#draggable5",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Правильно!");
    }

  });



  $("#draggable3").draggable();
  $("#droppable3").droppable({
    accept: "#draggable3",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Правильно!");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#draggable,
#draggable2,
#draggable3,
#draggable4,
#draggable5 {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  background: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

#droppable,
#droppable2,
#droppable3,
#droppable4,
#droppable5 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

h3 {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>1 + 1</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable2" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>10</p>
</div>
<div id="draggable4" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>2+3</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>5+5</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable3" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>3</p>
</div>
<div id="draggable3" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>1+2</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable4" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: приведите код в порядок, что бы можно было вам помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в Вашем случае, можно написать что-то подобное(см. ниже).

Но данный вариант плох тем, что это всего лишь костыль, хоть он и работает.

Если хотите более грамотно организовать код, то можно самим `div` элементам добавить атрибут, например `data-completed`, ставить им `1` или `0` при успехе и фейле соответственно, и по ним определять успешность решения.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      accept: "#draggable",
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
      },
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Правильно!" );
        checkResult();
      }
    });

    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable2" ).droppable({
      accept: "#draggable2",
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
      },
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Правильно!" );
        checkResult();
      }
    });

    $( "#draggable4" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable4" ).droppable({
      accept: "#draggable4",
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
      },
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Правильно!" );
        checkResult();
      }
    });

    $( "#draggable5" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable5" ).droppable({
      accept: "#draggable5",
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
      },
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Правильно!" );
        checkResult();
      }
    });

    $( "#draggable3" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable3" ).droppable({
      accept: "#draggable3",
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-default"
      },
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Правильно!" );
        checkResult();
      }
    });
 });
 
  var checkResult = function() {
    if($('.ui-widget-header p').text().split('!').length == 5) {
      alert('Вы выиграли!');
    }
  };
```

```css
  #draggable, #draggable2, #draggable3, #draggable4, #draggable5 { width: 90px; height: 90px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; background: grey; border:2px solid; }
  #droppable, #droppable2, #droppable3 , #droppable4, #droppable5  { width: 120px; height: 120px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; background: grey; border:2px solid; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>1 + 1</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable2" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>10</p>
</div>


<div id="draggable4" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>2+3</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>2</p>
</div>




<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>5+5</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable3" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>3</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable3" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>1+2</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable4" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>5</p>
</div>
```